# Retrieve and display image from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have successfully store an image in mySql. I want to retrieve in out and display it in website with an a href button that able to enlarge it.

This is my database table structure

```
-- Table structure for table `poster`
--

CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `img_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `img_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `img` blob NOT NULL,
  `img_type` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `img_size` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`img_id`)
)
```

Place to display image

```
<div class="col-md-5 text-dimension">
        <?php
            $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
            mysql_select_db("isiti");

            if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
             {
                echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
             }

            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM poster ORDER BY year DESC LIMIT 0, 5000");
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    $id=$row['img_id'];
                    echo '<a href="img_disp.php?image_id='.$id.'" data-lightbox="image-1" title="©ISITI-CoERI"><center><img src="img_disp.php?image_id='.$id.'" alt="poster1" width="200" height="250"><br></a><br><br>';
                    echo '<span class=right><a href="edit_form.php?id='.$id.'">[edit]</a>
                    <a name="delete" id="delete" href="public_delete.php?id='.$id.'">[delete]</a></span>';
                }
        ?>
```

This is img_disp.php

```
<?php

   // Connect to the database
        $host="localhost"; // Host name 
        $username="root"; // Mysql username 
        $password=""; // Mysql password 
        $db_name="isiti"; // Database name 
        $tbl_name="poster"; // Table name 

        $conn = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password"); 
        if(! $conn )
        {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        if (isset($_GET["image_id"]) && !empty($_GET["image_id"])) 
            {                           
                $id =$_GET["image_id"];
            }

        mysql_select_db($db_name);

  $sql="SELECT * from poster where id='$id'";

  $query=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

  while($result=mysql_fetch_array($query)){     
    header('Content-type:'.$result['img_type'].'');
    echo $result['img'];
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$result['img_name'].'"');      
  }
?>
```

The problem is ... the image do not show out. for both  or pop up.

Comment: You can't do any more header()s after an echo. Must send all the headers first, and only then send the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are using echo, which is meant to handle strings. Also you might want to consider other ways to store the image, rather than using mysql. Anyway the proper way to do it is to open up a file stream, and then put the data in their. Also you're going to need a separate file to handle the pictures, because you can only change the header for the whole file. This means you'll need one file to create a display page for the pictures, and another one to pull up your pictures.

```
$write=fopen("php://output","w");
fwrite($write,$results['img']);
fclose($write);
```

Also I'm not sure you have the structure right for the mysql results.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store all your images in disk [File System] instead of MySQL.
You can also encrypt your image and store it in .dat file. This will ensure security of your images.

In MySQL just store the path to that particular image. When you retrieve records from MySQL

```
go to the image path
get image
decrypt it (Optional, Only if you have encrypted it before)
and display the image..
```

Comment: how to store the image into file system ? is there any example ?

Comment: If you are allowing users to upload images then you can use PHP move_uploaded_file to save uploaded images / files into your folder. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php